# Enabling gzip compression for NextJs old version (prior to 9.0.7)

Tags: nginx, gzip, next.js

As titled,

Is there any way to enable gzip compression for old NextJs? My project uses NextJs version 9.0.1, while version 9.0.7 is the version that enables gzip compression by default.

Updating NextJs is not an option for now, due to the large code base this project has. Any update to NextJs might incur large code change or structuring change, so i don't want to take risk for that.

I tried installing [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) package, and then enabling gzip from nginx using the following config inside the server block.

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 0;
```

But still didnt work.

Need some help here on how to make this happen.

Comment: Do you have a custom server?

Comment: Nope i dont have. Is it really needed? Cant i just make it work from next.config.js's webpack configuration?

Comment: It is not related to build time (next.config) but runtime. If you have a ngnix in front of your next app you can do it with it.